# Unable to build IAR from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, iar

I'm having problems building an IAR project from Jenkins windows batch plugin. However the same command works perfectly fine directly from the same machines built in command prompt.

Build command: "C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.4\common\bin\iarbuild" protective\iar_project\cpup_project.ewp -build Debug -log all

When building from Jenkins the following error occur:

**Fatal Error[c0000142]: Uncontrolled termination**

**Error while running C/C++ Compiler**

The same build, that is the exact same version, has previously worked from Jenkins too. No aditional upgrades has been made to Jenkins.

System: Windows XP

Jenkins version: 1.466.1

Does anyone know what this is caused by?

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I have an additional webserver running with a wiki on the same machine, when I stopped this service (Apache) the IAR build worked again!

I really don't know what could be the conflict between the windows batch command in Jenkins and the Apache webserver. Jenkins and the webserver run on completely different ports.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem running iarbulid from jenkins on an xp machine.  I observed iarbuild failing with the same error message.

Based on searches for the term c0000142 (eg. [CreateProcess succeeds, but GetExitCodeProcess returns C0000142](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425106/createprocess-succeeds-but-getexitcodeprocess-returns-c0000142)), and my own observation with procmon I think it has to do with iccarm referencing user32.dll, probably unnecessarily, which seems like it can be problematic in a service.  The problem appears to go away by changing the jenkins service to log on as a user however.

Interestingly, prior to that change, iccarm would sometime fail and sometimes succeed.  My build was composed of several calls to iarbuild to generate library dependencies, followed by a call to build my application.  The library builds would always succeed, but the final application build would usually fail with the above error.  I haven't gotten to the bottom of that difference however.