# Creating a process to run as another user

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

I have a C# Windows service running with elevated privileges.  One of the service's jobs is to create a new local user account and perform some setup tasks with that account (set some registry settings, et cetera).  The service is running under the "Local System" account.

### Privileges in manifest

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

### Code that spawns the process

```
using (var proc = new Process())
using (var password = new SecureString())
{
   foreach (var c in accountPassword)
   {
      password.AppendChar(c);
   }
   proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
      pathToExecutable,
      arguments)
   {
      LoadUserProfile = true,
      UseShellExecute = false,
      CreateNoWindow = true,
      RedirectStandardError = true,
      RedirectStandardInput = true,
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      Domain = accountDomain,
      UserName = accountName,
      Password = password
   };
   StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter(), errWriter = new StringWriter();
   proc.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => outWriter.Write(e.Data);
   proc.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => errWriter.Write(e.Data);
   proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
   proc.Start(); // <-- exception thrown here
   ...
```

### Resulting exception

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
  at ...
```

### Experiments

If I go to the local services control panel, I can change the service so it runs as the administrator's account (i.e. "JoeAdmin", not "administrator"), and the program is successful.  Here is the part that gets frustrating: I tried running `whoami.exe /priv` from the service to see what privileges I had as "JoeAdmin" that I didn't have as "Local System" that would cause the program to fail.  Spoiler: according to whoami, "Local System" has all of the privileges that "JoeAdmin" has, with one exception (SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege, and I hope that's not important).

#### Priviliges for Local System

(As a reminder, the operation failed with these privileges.)

```
PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                  Description                               State   
=============================== ========================================= ========
SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege   Replace a process level token             Disabled
SeLockMemoryPrivilege           Lock pages in memory                      Enabled 
SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege        Adjust memory quotas for a process        Disabled
SeTcbPrivilege                  Act as part of the operating system       Enabled 
SeSecurityPrivilege             Manage auditing and security log          Disabled
SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege        Take ownership of files or other objects  Disabled
SeLoadDriverPrivilege           Load and unload device drivers            Disabled
SeSystemProfilePrivilege        Profile system performance                Enabled 
SeSystemtimePrivilege           Change the system time                    Disabled
SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege Profile single process                    Enabled 
SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege Increase scheduling priority              Enabled 
SeCreatePagefilePrivilege       Create a pagefile                         Enabled 
SeCreatePermanentPrivilege      Create permanent shared objects           Enabled 
SeBackupPrivilege               Back up files and directories             Disabled
SeRestorePrivilege              Restore files and directories             Disabled
SeShutdownPrivilege             Shut down the system                      Disabled
SeDebugPrivilege                Debug programs                            Enabled 
SeAuditPrivilege                Generate security audits                  Enabled 
SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege    Modify firmware environment values        Disabled
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege         Bypass traverse checking                  Enabled 
SeUndockPrivilege               Remove computer from docking station      Disabled
SeManageVolumePrivilege         Perform volume maintenance tasks          Disabled
SeImpersonatePrivilege          Impersonate a client after authentication Enabled 
SeCreateGlobalPrivilege         Create global objects                     Enabled 
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege   Increase a process working set            Enabled 
SeTimeZonePrivilege             Change the time zone                      Enabled 
SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege   Create symbolic links                     Enabled
```

#### Privileges for JoeAdmin

(The operation succeeded with these privileges.)

```
PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                  Description                               State   
=============================== ========================================= ========
SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege        Adjust memory quotas for a process        Disabled
SeSecurityPrivilege             Manage auditing and security log          Disabled
SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege        Take ownership of files or other objects  Disabled
SeLoadDriverPrivilege           Load and unload device drivers            Disabled
SeSystemProfilePrivilege        Profile system performance                Disabled
SeSystemtimePrivilege           Change the system time                    Disabled
SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege Profile single process                    Disabled
SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege Increase scheduling priority              Disabled
SeCreatePagefilePrivilege       Create a pagefile                         Disabled
SeBackupPrivilege               Back up files and directories             Disabled
SeRestorePrivilege              Restore files and directories             Disabled
SeShutdownPrivilege             Shut down the system                      Disabled
SeDebugPrivilege                Debug programs                            Disabled
SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege    Modify firmware environment values        Disabled
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege         Bypass traverse checking                  Enabled 
SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege       Force shutdown from a remote system       Disabled
SeUndockPrivilege               Remove computer from docking station      Disabled
SeManageVolumePrivilege         Perform volume maintenance tasks          Disabled
SeImpersonatePrivilege          Impersonate a client after authentication Enabled 
SeCreateGlobalPrivilege         Create global objects                     Enabled 
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege   Increase a process working set            Disabled
SeTimeZonePrivilege             Change the time zone                      Disabled
SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege   Create symbolic links                     Disabled
```

### The question

Can I spawn the process from the Local System account? Or,

The service is installed by a WiX installer, is there a way I can give the service the correct privileges from the installer?

```
<ServiceInstall
   Id="ServiceInstaller"
   Type="ownProcess"
   Name="MyCoolService"
   DisplayName="My Cool Service"
   Description="My Cool Service Component"
   Start="auto"
   ErrorControl="normal" />
```

Comment: One thing you can try is put `proc.Start();` inside an impersonation block. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/1082327) explains how to perform impersonation.

Comment: The problem is most likely related to the access rights of the target user to the window station, ala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256665/process-started-from-service-with-createprocesswithlogonw-terminates-right-away

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Interesting, that could explain things.  Could this be solved by making some change to the executable I'm running, so it doesn't attempt the access?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I do know that an executable that doesn't attempt to display anything (including a console window) needs less permissions; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/21716527/886887

Comment: It is possible that an executable which does not reference user32.dll or gdi32.dll might run.  So if you can restrict yourself to kernel32.dll only you might be OK.  (Not sure whether that would be considered supported though.)