# Launching CMD from windows service results in exception code 0xC0000142

Tags: windows, service, createprocess, createprocesswithlogonw

We have a service application that launches `CMD.exe` with Stdin/Stdout/Stderr
redirected to a named pipe.  The Service is running as an administrator account
(It is **NOT** running as `LocalSystem`). The development environment is Windows 8.1 Pro.

When we launch `CMD.exe` using `CreateProcessWithLogonW()`, it starts and
immediate ends with exit code **0xc0000142**.  If instead, we launch CMD using
`CreateProcess()`, it works fine, which leads me to believe we are tripping over
some sort of security model in windows. Note -- the credentials we pass are definitely valid.

This security model theory I believe is further confirmed by the fact that our
unittest framework has no problem running `CreateProcessWithLogonW()` from user
space -- but when we move this infrastructure into a windows service it fails. Note -- when we run the unittest, we run using the same administrator account we are using to run the service.

A number of Internet threads discuss exception code 0xC0000142 on google and SO,
but they seem to focus on the possibility of a virus outbreak of some sort. We
have run the appropriate `sfc/scannow` to confirm we have a fresh & healthy
windows environment. And again I do not believe this is a virus due to the fact
that our unittest framework works flawlessly from user space -- it only
generates the exception code from within a service:

There are a total a four log entries that are recorded when we encounter the
exception code; two for `CONHOST.exe` and two for `CMD.exe`. I have reproduced the relevant entries below.

CONHOST.exe entries:

```
Faulting application name: conhost.exe, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x5450410b
Faulting module name: USER32.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18202, time stamp: 0x569e7d02
Exception code: 0xc0000142
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ecdd0

Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: conhost.exe
P2: 6.3.9600.17415
P3: 5450410b
P4: USER32.dll
P5: 6.3.9600.18202
P6: 569e7d02
P7: c0000142
P8: 00000000000ecdd0
P9: 
P10:
```

CMD.exe entries

```
Faulting application name: cmd.exe, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x545042b1
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18202, time stamp: 0x569e7d02
Exception code: 0xc0000142
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ecdd0

Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: cmd.exe
P2: 6.3.9600.17415
P3: 545042b1
P4: KERNELBASE.dll
P5: 6.3.9600.18202
P6: 569e7d02
P7: c0000142
P8: 00000000000ecdd0
P9: 
P10:
```

I'd be happy to share code -- but due to the fact this is windows service, even
a minimally reproducible example is going to be quite long. I was hoping
someone might recognize the issue and point us to some sort of RTFM/security
docs from MSDN that might lead us down the right path?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/20256665/1207195

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/06/03/what-is-up-with-the-application-failed-to-initialize-properly-0xc0000142-error/